# MySQL: как создать INSERT-триггер для поля, снабженного атрибутом AUTO_INCREMENT?

Tags: mysql, триггер

MySQL. У меня есть таблица с автоинкрементным полем, являющимся первичным ключом:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
 id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 field VARCHAR(45)
);
```

Во второе поле я хочу записать значение, которое должно быть вычислено на базе значения первичного ключа.

Это не работает:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `myTable_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `myTable` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 UPDATE myTable SET field=CONCAT(NEW.id,"T") WHERE id=NEW.id;
END;
```

При попытке добавить я получаю ошибку MySQL:

> Can`t update table "myTable" in stored function/trigger because it is
>   already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

И следующий вариант тоже не работает:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `myTable_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `myTable` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 SET NEW.field=CONCAT(NEW.id,"T");
END;
```

Поскольку в этом случае NEW.did еще не определен.

Как мне решить поставленную задачу? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Будет работать вот в таком виде:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `myTable_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `myTable` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 SET @new_field = "";
 SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT INTO @new_field
  FROM information_schema.tables
  WHERE table_name = 'myTable'
  AND table_schema = DATABASE();
 SET NEW.field=CONCAT("A",@new_field);
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Borik Bobrujskov, это будет работать только для "инсерта" одной записи. Для "инсерта" многих записей - только у первой записи будет корректное значение.

Немного избыточный "тригер", но гибки и работающий:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `myTable_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `myTable`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 SET NEW.id = IF(NEW.id > 0, NEW.id, (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME='myTable'));
 IF NEW.field IS NULL THEN
    SET NEW.field = NEW.id;
 END IF; 
END;
```